# Only 5 platonic hedrons, connectivity only proof?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, polygons, discrete-geometry

I am reading a course on discrete differential geometry and found this neat problem:

[image]

After thinking about it for 15 minutes curiosity got the better of me and I cheated. And here's one possible proof:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/platonic-solids-why-five.html

However, that used angles, and the hint implies you can do it only with the connectivity (I assume Euler's formula?).

I was wondering if someone could prove this with only connectivity information.

Comment: I think they need to be more specific about how they define their platonic solids. There are plenty of genus zero polyhedra where every face is identical. A standard 10-sided die with kite-shaped sides, for instance (search "d10 die" for pictures if you don't already know what they look like). Without a functioning definition, there is no way we can prove there are only 5 of them.

Comment: Assume the valence at each vertex is the same, the D10 does not obey that restriction.

Comment: Sure, that's a reasonable correction. Also, having the faces be _regular polygons_ is usually part of the definition. But they should've _said so in the text_. If you are to prove something as an exercise, you can't be guessing at half the assumptions you have to use. Your text has failed at posing a well-formed problem.

Comment: Regular polygons means same length and angles, but the question states that's not needed. So I suspect the valence should be enough.

Comment: I usually don't consider solids to be Platonic unless the sides are regular. But no, I don't think we need to use this regularity to show that they are the only ones. Euler characteristic and some nice counting-the-same-thing-two-different-ways ought to do the trick.

Comment: The "connectivity" or combinatorial argument (with Euler's formula) tells us that there's five cases for how many faces of what shape meet at a vertex. If we add information about vertices and angles, it's intuitive that there's only one way to build the polyhedron. Actually, the *graphs* are also unique, but that's harder to prove: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991092/characterization-of-platonic-graphs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show here that the cube is the only Platonic solid with square faces.

We start with a genus 0 polyhedron with square faces, and three edges and three faces to each vertex. Using only this information and the Euler characteristic, what can we say?

Well, we have $V-E+F = 2$, for starters (where, as is conventional, $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ is the number of edges, and $F$ is the number of faces). Next, each edge is the edge of two faces, and each face has four edges, so we get that $4F = 2E$. Finally, from each edge going between two vertices, we get $2E = 3V$. This is three equations in three unknowns, and solving them is rather straight-forward: We get $V = 8, E = 12, F = 6$. This necessarily gives us a cube.

What about four edges and four faces to each vertex? Setting up the same equations, we get
$$
\cases{V-E+F = 2\\
4F = 2E\\
2E = 4V}
$$
Trying to solve these, we get $0 = 2$, so this is impossible. Trying with more than four will give negative solutions, which is absurd. So we conclude that the cube is the only Platonic solid with square faces.

The three solids with triangular faces and the one solid with pentagonal faces may be solved completely analogously.

Comment: I understand the general idea but I will admit I am getting lost when you setup your equalities for example:
"Next, each edge is the edge of two faces, and each face has four edges, so we get that $4F=2E$" This is likely more a language comprehension problem than a math one but could you please be a little more explicit there? It'd help me lots : )

Comment: What I mean is $4F=2E \iff 2F=E$ i,e, the number of faces is twice the number of edges. But a cube has 6 faces and 12 edges, which is the opposite of what the equation suggests.

Comment: @Makogan Count all the edges twice, in two ways: 1) By counting all the edges twice (giving $2E$). 2) By counting all faces, then multiply by 4 because each face has 4 edges (giving $4F$) (since each edge is included in two faces, this counts the edges twice). These must be equal as they count the same thing, giving $4F = 2E$. The final equation $2E = 3V$ comes from a similar process on vertices and edges.

Comment: @Makogan No, it's not opposite at all. There are $6$ faces, which is to say $F = 6$. So $2F = 12$. There are $12$ edges, which is to say $E = 12$. So we do indeed get $2F = E$.